# Emboss a Bitmap without losing color in c# Programatically

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I want to apply emboss and sketch effect on a bitmap with out losing its color.
I have applied color effects but no luck with emboss yet.

Any body have solution for it?
Please help

Answer (score 0):

you can apply an hi-pass filter on image. This means replace the value of a pixel with the absolute difference between the pixel and the next pixel.

Something like this:

```
Bitmap img = new Bitmap(100, 100); //your image
        Bitmap embossed = new Bitmap(img); //create a clone
        for (int i = 0; i < img.Width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < img.Height; j++)
            {
                Color c = img.GetPixel(i, j);
                Color newColor;
                if ((i == img.Width - 1))
                {
                    newColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0);
                }
                else
                {
                    Color next = img.GetPixel(x + 1, y);

                    newColor = Color.FromArgb(
                        Math.Abs((byte)((int)c.R - (int) next.R)),
                        Math.Abs((byte)((int)c.G - (int) next.G)),
                        Math.Abs((byte)((int)c.B - (int) next.B)));

                }
                embossed.SetPixel(i, j, newColor);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response i am already done with the gray emboss i want to emboss it without loosing its color as we can do in Html5. Any idea about that?

Answer (score 0):

When you done with the gray emboss, you could set the alpha values of the image pixels according to the result of the emboss.

Answer (score 0):

Consider it as two operations.  Firstly, generate the grey embossed image (which you say you have achieved) then to make a coloured embossed image you perform a mix operation between between the original image and the embossed image.  There is no single right choice for what form of operation to use. It comes down to what effect you are wishing to achieve.

if you work on the assumption that you have a colour image (R,G,B) and a grey emboss image (E) with each component being a byte.  this gives you (for each pixel) 4 values in the range of 0..255;

since you probably want the dark areas of the emboss to show darker and the bright areas to show brighter, it's useful to have a centred grey level.

```
w=(E/128)-1; // convert 0..255 range to -1..1
```

Now where w is negative things should get darker and where w is positive w should get brighter.

```
outputR = R + (R*w);
outputG = G + (G*w);
outputB = B + (B*w);
```

This will give you Black where w is - 1.  and double the brightness (R*2,G*2,B*2) when w is 1.   That will produce a coloured embossed effect.  Don't forget to limit the result to 0..255 though. If it goes higher cap it. if (x>255) x=255;

That should preserve the colours nicely but may not be exactly what you are after.  If you want the white in the embossed image to be more than just doubled then you can try different formula.

```
outputR = R * (10**w);   // w==0 has no effect
outputG = G * (10**w);   // w==1 is 10 times brighter
outputB = B * (10**w);   // w==-1 is 0.1 brightness
```

There are many many more possibilities.
you can convert the RGB to [YUV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV) and then apply the emboss change directly to the Y component. Then convert back to RGB.

The right choice is more of a matter of taste than optimally correct formula.

Comment: Lerc I am getting Yuv(nv21 format) bytes from Camera.onPreviewFrame(). How can i change its y component in order to get emboss effect. Can you add code to it.

Comment: Y directly represents brightness so for lightening/darkening you don't need to touch the U and V at all.   nv21 uses an 8 bit Y plane so you could just add the emboss value directly to the Y value for each pixel.  if it goes below zero or above 255 bound it to those levels.